# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'reservationBinding' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I started to work with thymeleaf in a basic project. When I try to put th:field="*{name}" in form, comes error with thymeleaf parsing. Only with  th:object="${reservationBinding}" without any th:fields works correctly. I can't understand why doesn't work with th:filed.

**Here is my controller where I set the message:**

```
@Controller
public class ReservationController {

   @GetMapping("/reservation")
   public String checkFOrReservationGet(Model model){
           model.addAttribute ("reservationBinding",new ReservationBinding ());

       return "index";
   }

    @PostMapping("/reservation")

    public String checkForReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute() ReservationBinding reservationBinding,
                                      Model model,
                                      BindingResult bindingResult,
                                      RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                      HttpSession httpSession){

           // model.addAttribute ("reservationBinding",new ReservationBinding ());
            if(bindingResult.hasErrors ()){
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute ("reservationBinding",reservationBinding);
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute ("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.reservationBinding",bindingResult);
                return "redirect:#book-a-table";
            }


        return "redirect:#book-a-table";

    }
```

**Here is my html form**

```
 <form action="#book-a-table" th:action="@{/reservation}" method="post"  th:object="${reservationBinding}" >

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group" >
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
                     placeholder="name" data-rule="minlen:4"
                th:field="*{name}"
                     data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">

              <div  class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email"

                     data-msg="Please enter a valid email">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone" data-rule="minlen:4"

                     data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
              <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date" data-rule="minlen:4"

                     data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time" data-rule="minlen:4"

                     data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 form-group mt-3">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="people" id="people" placeholder="# of people"

                     data-rule="minlen:1" data-msg="Please enter at least 1 chars">
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5"

                      placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your booking request was sent. We will call back or send an Email to confirm your reservation. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit"  >Send Message</button></div>

        </form>
```

**This is my bindingModel**

```
public class ReservationBinding {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private int People;
    private String message;

    public ReservationBinding(){
    }


//    @Length(min = 2, message = "Username length must be minimum two characters!.")
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "Enter valid email address.")
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    @Length(min = 9, message = "Enter valid phone number.")
    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
        return this;
    }

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setDate(String date){
        this.date = date;
        return this;
    }

    @Column(name = "time")
    @Length(min = 2, message = "Enter a valid time for check in.")
    public String getTime(){
        return time;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setTime(String time){
        this.time = time;
        return this;
    }

    @Min(value = 2, message = "What is the number of the guests")
    public int getPeople(){
        return People;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setPeople(int people){
        People = people;
        return this;
    }


    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    public ReservationBinding setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea, why alone th:object map the properties and when I put th:field doesn't work and comes

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing 
(template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]"

 Error during execution of processor 
'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' 
(template: "index" - line 564, col 17)
```

Comment: Can you try replacing `return "redirect:#book-a-table";` with `return "redirect:/book-a-table";`? I have never seen a redirect with a hash (`#`).

Comment: yes of course. I try but this is not the problem. The big Problem is when I put th:filed="*{name}" and don' t want to parse. The properties are correct. And without any th:fileds works. If you want we can make teamviewer connection and i can show you for 5 min. My Linked in -> Orlin Baltadzhiev